# Javascript, ajax and django not redirecting page and returning value as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to make a Django and Ajax based Login View with Mobile Number verification via a One Time Password (OTP). When the User signups, his mobile number is sent an OTP, which he has to enter and confirm.

Now, let's say the user did not authenticate his mobile number before and now tries to login into the website, I want him to first verify the mobile number via the OTP that was sent to his mobile number and then he can further log into the site.

My code for signup in views.py is:

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    first_name = request.POST.get("fname")
    last_name = request.POST.get("lname")
    mobile = request.POST.get("telephone")
    email = request.POST.get("email")
    password = request.POST.get("password")

    try:
        #mobilecheck = Customer.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
        emailcheck = Customer.objects.get(email=email)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        user = Customer.objects.create_user(email, password, mobile=mobile, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, is_active=False)

        otp = randint(1000,9999)
        message = "Verification code for Delimedy.com is : " + str(otp)

        mOTP = MobileOTP(customer=user, otp=otp)
        mOTP.save()

        sendotp(mobile, message)

        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        auth_login(request, user)

        return HttpResponse("success")

    else:
        return HttpResponse("conflict")

else:
    return render(request, "registration/signup.html", {
    "title":"Signup",
    })
```

And code for login in views.py is :

```
def login(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            if user.is_active:
                return HttpResponse("success", content_type="text/plain")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("notverified", content_type="text/plain")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("mismatch", content_type="text/plain")
    else:
        return render(request, "registration/login.html", {
        "title":"Login to Delimedy"
        })
```

And the contents of my .js file for the Ajax function calling is:

```
$('#login-button').on('click', function(){
    var preloader = $('#overlay-screen');
    preloader.removeClass('hide');

    var redirectTo = $(this).attr("rel");

    var email = $('#email');
    if(email.val().length == 0) {
        email.removeClass('valid');
        email.addClass('invalid');
        preloader.addClass('hide');
        return;
    }
    var password = $('#password');
    if(password.val().length == 0) {
        password.removeClass('valid');
        password.addClass('invalid');
        preloader.addClass('hide');
        return;
    }
    var csrf_token = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    var rememberme = $('#remember').is(':checked');
    var dataString = 'email='+email.val()+'&password='+password.val()+'&csrfmiddlewaretoken='+csrf_token;
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/account/login/",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                preloader.addClass('hide');
                if(data == 'email_blank') {
                    email.removeClass('valid');
                            email.addClass('invalid');
                            return;
                }
                else if(data == 'password_blank') {
                    password.removeClass('valid');
                            password.addClass('invalid');
                            return;
                }
                else if(data == 'success') {
                  window.location.href = "/";
                }
                        else if(data == 'notverified') {
                            window.location.href="/account/login/"
                        }
                else if(data == "mismatch") {
                    alert("Mobile Number and Password doesn't match.");
                }
                else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
});
```

The problem with the login form is that, If try to login and the login is successful, instead of redirecting to the page, it opens a page with the text "success" and let's say the user is registered and not active but tries to login, does not get redirected to verifyotp page but a page with just "notverified" written. How do I fix it?

Comment: can you share form html as well.

Answer (score 0):

rather than: return HttpResponse("success", content_type="text/plain")

You should have: return redirect(myurl)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Don't know if it is the question, but django will refresh current page after a click on the button, to prevent this you could add in js:

return false;

or

e.preventDefault();